# Flink 1.6 TimeoutException while submitting the job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using flink 1.6 and I am getting random timeout issues while submitting the job in the flink Job manager.

Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Exception is not retryable.

```
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$5(FutureUtils.java:213)

    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)

    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)

    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)

    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:793)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

```
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)

    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)

    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)

    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)

    ... 10 more
```

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Comment: Could you share the cluster entrypoint logs with us? It would also be good to use Flink 1.6.2. In this version Flink gives you better error messages on the client side.

Comment: There were no other messages in the jobmanager as well as the task manager